# How to create iCalendar Recurrence(RRULE) Event Parser?

Tags: java, icalendar, rrule

I need a RRULE Parser method, in which I can provide information like start date of event, end date of event and RRULE for that event. Method should return the list of dates on which that event will occur.

I tried using google library and ical, but not able to create method.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use the google calendar APIs, they have some good [quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview) for various different programming languages. I recently followed the Ruby one without any issues.  This gets you up and running with some base code to list the next few events in a calendar.
In order to use this the way you describe though, you'd need to add the event to your calendar via one API call and then get the occurrences via another API call.

**Alternatively** the JavaScript library [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) does more exactly what you describe. See [halfway down the readme](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule#rrulefromstringrfcstring) for the following examples.

Including start date in RRULE definition:

```
var str = "FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20180201T093000Z;UNTIL=20180301T093000Z";
var rule = RRule.fromString(str);

rule.all(); // enumerate occurrences
```

Provide RRULE and start date separately:

```
var options = RRule.parseString("FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=6");
options.dtstart = new Date(2018, 2, 1, 9, 30);
options.until = new Date(2018, 3, 1, 9, 30);
var rule = new RRule(options);

rule.all(); // enumerate occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, the [Zap Cal PHP library](https://icalendar.org/php-library.html) at [iCalendar.org](http://icalendar.org) can expand RRULE strings into an array of dates. See the example recurringdate.php in the examples folder on how to do it. but it is basically like this:

```
$rd = new ZCRecurringDate($rrule, $startdate);
//use $maxdate to avoid infinitely repeating dates
$dates = $rd->getDates($maxdate);
```

$dates contains an array of the recurring dates